# All formal group has Frobenius power series as homomorphisms?(Lubin Tate theory)

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory, formal-groups

Let $L/ \Bbb{Q}_p$ be finite extension, $o$ be it's ring of integers.
**Frobenius power series** is defined as $Φ(X)∈o[[X]]$ s.t.$Φ(X)＝πX＋$(higher term) and $Φ(X)≡X^qmodπo[X]$.

It is well known that
For given **Frobenius power series**,there exists unique formal group which has $Φ(X)$ as homomorphism.

For example, $Φ(X)＝(1＋X)^p-1$ is homomorphism of formal group $F(X,Y)＝X＋Y＋XY$.

My question is, does all formal group have **Frobenius power series** as homomorphism?
For example, formal group $G(X,Y)＝X＋Y$ has Frobenius power series as homomorphism?

Comment: The endomorphisms of the additive formal group are the $X\to a X$ for $a\in L$

Comment: How can I prove that ? Do you have reference ? Every formal group is isom to formal additive group, so I guess I can pull back From power series on multiplicative formal group by log.

Comment: In characteristic $0$ only $\phi(t)=at$ is an homomorphism of the addtive formal group. Assume the opposite, write $\phi(t) = at+bt^n+O(t^{n+1})$ with $b\in L^*,n\ge 2$, then $\phi(X+Y)=\phi(X)+\phi(Y)$ in $L[[X,Y]]$   gives that $(X+X)^n = X^n+Y^n $ in $L[[X,Y]]/(X,Y)^{n+1}$ which is a contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, formal groups with endomorphisms of that shape are exceptional. These formal groups have in some sense a maximal ring of endomorphisms, while a typical formal group of finite height has only $\Bbb Z_p$ as endomorphism ring.

The infinite-height formal groups like the additive formal group $X+Y$ show just the opposite behavior: the endomorphisms defined over a ring $\mathfrak o$ of the sort you mention consist of all $\mathfrak o$: the endomorphism ring increases when $\mathfrak o$ is replaced by a larger ring, whereas the endomorphism ring of a finite-height formal group has $\Bbb Z_p$-rank bounded by the height.

Comment: Thank you ! I understand formal group which has Frob power series as homomorphism is very rare. I only know formal multiplicative group. Could you tell me formal groups except for $X＋Y＋XY$, which has Frob power series as homomorphism ?

Comment: Well, there’s the paper by John Tate and me that shows that if $\pi$ is a prime element of your ring $\mathfrak o$ and the residue field lhs $q=p^m$ elements, then there’s a formal group that has $\pi X+X^q$ as endomorphism. You build up the whole formal group from that tiny bit of information, but the f.g. formula is never a polynomial. Alternatively, you can build up your formal group from a logarithm of this shape: $L(X)=X+X^q/\pi+X^{q^2}/\pi^2+\cdots$. That’s in Hazewinkel’s encyclopedic book, an excellent reference.